# System.getProperty Change Listener

Tags: java

Is there any way to check if `System.getProperty(...)` value has changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly doubt that there is a general way since AFAIK a lot of the properties are provided by the OS and code is integrated into the VM.
I mean, you could just check periodically but I'm pretty sure you've ruled that out already.

What properties exactly do you want to know about?

Comment: I am setting customized property to System.setProperty 
and later retrieve.

Comment: Maybe you could add some more detail to the question as to *why* you're storing your customized property in the System properties. There may be better alternatives.